# After deployment of ssas tabular cube,I could not see any Object under any folder. can you please help me with this

Tags: ssas-tabular

I created the SSAS Tabular Data Model Solution in VS 2019 and Deployed that in SSAS 2017 Analysis services. After deployment I could not see any Object under any folder. can you please help me with this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2HYUG.png)

Comment: Did you get some error message?
Are you sure, that you deploy your model to the correct server/instance?

I use TabularEditor instead of VS to deploying my model (For me is easier to use this software). 

https://github.com/otykier/TabularEditor/releases/tag/2.12.1

Comment: No Error Message and also I am using correct server for deployment. which compatibility level i need to select.could you pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

In VS 2019, open Model.bim and click on a table in the model viewer. Then select **Project > Your_Model Properties** (This is the last option in the **Project** menu). Under **Deployment Server**, validate the server and database names. I also recommend changing **Processing Option** from **Default** to **Full** under **Deployment Options** if your model processes quickly.

To deploy, use either of two the **Deploy** options under the **Build** menu. You should get a message after the model has deployed, or error messages under **View > Error List**.

If this does not resolve your issue, please show a picture of your model from the **Tabular Model Explorer** in VS and the message you get after deploying.